# Loopless algorithm for generating permutations (Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter)

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

The following is a description of the well-known Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm to generate all permutations of an $n$-element ground set using adjacent transpositions.
In fact, it is a loopless implementation, i.e., the time between two successively generated permutations is constant, independent of $n$.

[image]

In addition to the permutation array $a$, the algorithm uses four auxiliary arrays: the inverse permutation $a'$, the inversion table $c$, and two more arrays $o$ and $e$ as explained in the pseudocode above.

My question is: Is there a way to do this with fewer than four auxiliary arrays?

I looked into a paper by Sedgewick entitled "Permutation generation methods", and there he also uses four auxiliary arrays, though with a slightly different meaning. I know that it can be done with fewer arrays if we don't insist on a loopless algorithm, so I really want to insist on the loopless property. And I don't want to cheat like compressing the $\pm 1$s of the array $e$ in one of the other arrays, or concatenating two arrays. I am really interested in a genuinely simpler way of keeping track of the information needed.

Comment: I used something for multisets. It was pretty fast, and I think average time was constant.  If you are interested, I will see if I can recall it.  Gerhard "Thinks It Was Something Williams" Paseman, 2018.07.26.

Comment: Thank you! At the moment I care more about simplicity than about actual speed. And in particular I care about the loopless property.

Comment: Based on other postings, you probably know the work already. Aaron Williams has a 2008 paper on loopless generation of multiset permutations using prefixes. It might use four arrays though.  Gerhard "Kept From Running In Circles" Paseman, 2018.07.27.

Comment: I reviewed the algorithm. They used a single linked list with five pointers to parts of it. Prefix shifts are used to generate the permutations.  Hopefully this will serve.  Gerhard "Remembers Using Arrays For Pointers" Paseman, 2018.07.27.

Comment: I found “Loopless generation of multiset permutations using a constant number of variables by prefix shifts” by Williams at <https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1496770.1496877>